# Reapply updated configuration to a statefulset, using Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have a rather peculiar use case. Specifically, prior to the deployment of my statefulset I am deploying a ConfigMap which contains an environment variable setting (namely RECREATE_DATADIR) which instructs the pod's container to create a new data structure on the file system.
However, during the typical lifetime of the container the data structure should NOT be recreated. Hence, right after the pod is successfully running, I am changing the ConfigMap and then reapply it. Hence - if the pod ever fails, it won't recreate the data directory structure when it respawns.

How can I achieve this same result using Helm charts?

Comment: Could you put a flag in the filesystem itself?  For proving this out, you can `kubectl exec ... -- touch /etc/recreate.flag`, and if that's successful, add an administrative API to set it.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your approach. Do you mind elaborating this idea, Dave?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `job` as part of your helm chart, with the `post-install` helm hook which will have configmap edit permissions, will use a kubectl image (`bitnami/kubectl` for example), and it will patch the configmap to false using kubectl commands.

Comment: Interesting idea, that might work. I was in fact thinking of running a helm upgrade and update the configmap as part of the pipeline which runs the helm chart deployment.